# No norm consistent with given topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Given the (Frechet) topology on the Schwartz class $S(\mathbb{R}^d)$ induced by the seminorms $\rho_{\alpha \beta}f = \operatorname{sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}^d}|x^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}f|$, how can I show that there is no norm consistent with this topology? ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are multi-indices in $\mathbb{Z}^d$)

I'm not sure how to show that a space with this topology has no norm.  I tried to start by assuming by way of contradiction that there was a topology defined by some norm and finding some open set that was not in the above topology.  If I had to guess, the fact that the differentiation operator is not bounded would play a role.

Comment: You *really* ought to mention what space this is.

Comment: @tomasz No space was mentioned, but if I had to guess, it'd be the Schwartz class - I'll put that in the question.  Note - this isn't homework, but preparation for an exam.